# Reclassify patchy raster into sequentially numbered regions

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Imagine a raster:

```
library(raster)

r = raster(nrow=3, ncol=3)
r[] = c(1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1)
plot(r)
```

How could I reclassify *contiguous* patches (not on the diagonal) in ascending order? In this example, the three-cell patch on the left hand side of the plot is reclassified as '1', the top right patch as '2' and the bottom right patch as '3'.

The actual reclassified values (and the order they appear across the raster) is unimportant. What is important is that each 'island' of connected (or individual cells) is represented by a new, unique, number.

Comment: Do you need `r@data@values <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(r@data@values), values[!is.na(values)] <- seq_along(values[!is.na(values)])))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not quite, sadly. In your code the three cells on the left of the plot/raster each have a different value. They would all need to have the same value. Because there are three 'islands' in this example raster, the range of values should only be between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raster::clump` with argument `directions=4` to not connect on the diagonal (with this example data it does not matter, as there no such case).

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3, xmx=0)
values(r) <- c(1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1)
x <- clump(r, directions=4)
plot(x)
```

Note that I added `xmx=0` to avoid a global raster. Without that, there is only one patch as longitudes -180 and 180 are the same and thus the cells of the first and last columns are, in fact, connected.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I should have known there would be a solution within `raster`! I must have been putting the wrong search terms into Google because I didn't find this function anywhere.